# Who actually built this throne room?

Tags: monsterverse, godzilla-vs-kong

Inside the Hollow Earth, Kong and the Apex team find a throne room:

[image]

Who actually built this throne room?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ancient Kong *[precursors](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Precursors)* built the temple. It would appear that King Kong is the last scion of a relatively advanced culture that has [regressed into barbarism](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/FuturePrimitive).

> Jia looked at her, puzzled, then shook her head.
>
> The Iwi lived here with Kong’s family, yes, she signed. But this was
> built by Kong’s family.
>
> What do you mean? Ilene asked. How do you know?
>
> I remember the story now, Jia said. Look, nothing small here. **Nothing
> the size of Iwi. This was built by Kongs.**
>
> And in a sudden flash, Ilene realized that had to be true. **Humans
> could have built this place, given time, and numbers, and basic
> machines like block-and-tackle. But they hadn’t.** Now that she looked
> more closely, with different eyes, it didn’t look like human
> architecture, and not just because of the scale.
>
> <sub><sup>[Godzilla vs. Kong - Official Novelisation](https://wikizilla.org/wiki/Godzilla_vs._Kong:_The_Official_Movie_Novelization)</sup></sub>

This is confirmed in the *[Godzilla vs. Kong: One Will Fall - The Art of the Ultimate Battle Royale](https://wikizilla.org/wiki/Godzilla_vs._Kong:_One_Will_Fall_-_The_Art_of_the_Ultimate_Battle_Royale)* artbook. According to an interview with Production Designer Tom Hammock, the Kongs likely had human helpers also.

> Lead graphic designer Ellen Lampl created the pictorial graphics used in the floor mosaic. The mosaic, made from urethane and painted with a metallic terra-cotta sheen, depicted ape forms, lizard forms and some tiny Iwi figures beneath them.
> "*We imply that the Kongs might have had human help,*" says Hammock. "*Some of them islanders from Skull Island might have helped them build that temple.*"